# Staff availability form in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

I'm have trouble coming up with a solution to a staff availability form, for a live event facility.

The goal is to have someone in the office select start and end dates, which generates a list of upcoming events. This list will be seen by employees on WebDirect, and they will be able to mark whether they are available or not via checkbox. The people in the office will then be able to see who is available for the all upcoming events while scheduling.

The idea behind choosing the start and end date is so the office can selectively "publish" which dates the employees see, as well as having a log of all responses tied to that form.

I also want to limit the employee to only be able to see their responses to the form.

So far I have tables as follows:

```
Employee   Event   Availability   Form               Response
--------   -----   ------------   ----               --------
ID         ID      ID             ID                 ID
Name       Date    StartDate      fk_AvailabilityID  fk_EmployeeID   
           Title   EndDate        fk_ResponseID      Checkbox
```

All of the relationships are primary key = foreign key except Event Date has a relationship to Availability:

```
Date ≥ StartDate  AND
Date ≤ EndDate
```

Not really sure where to go past this or if this even is correct to begin with. I've experimented with a FormResponse table but not really sure what connections to make.

I'm fairly new to FileMaker and Databases in general, so laymens terms would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, instead of convoluted relationships, you could use a field in the event table as a publish flag and then perform a search for that in web direct upon login.

When the staff sets a start/end date, they run a script that sets the publish flag for these records only.

To match the logged in user to  an employee, you would need to store the account name in the employee table and match these upon login. Then set the privileges such that records can only be viewed when there is a match.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I see your point, but the only thing I don't really understand is why not having a relationship between the event and availability tables would be better than having one. Any advantages you see that I am missing?

Comment: Well, I tend to not use relationships for functions that are used time by time, as in not always "on". Keeps the relationship graph less cluttered. Also, it is easier to maintain and troubleshoot a specific script for a given purpose. In general, I try to put less and less functionality in the relationship graph, using it mostly to "drive" data and portals in layouts. Nothing stopping you from doing it your way, if you want.